# Div inside a div breaks the extraction of the whole div - Python/BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is the HTML Im working with:

```
<div id="post_message_64012736" class=" post">
<br>
Just testing something, please ignore this :D<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
    <div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">

            Quote:

    </div>


    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr><td class="quotearea">
    <div style="font-style:italic">New browser based game that was directly inspired by Candy Box, but is quite different from it.<br>
<br>
A Dark Room -</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
I have it running on a tab, pretty interesting. I still don't know how to get scales thought. You can only buy them or get them from the traps?<br>
<br>
Is there a Sentinel demo that doesn't require unity3d in the browser? Like a real windows demo?
</div>
```

This is the code Im using, pretty simple:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for i in soup.findAll("div",class_=" post"):
    print i.text
```

But I only get this output:

```
Just testing something, please ignore this :D







            Quote:




New browser based game that was directly inspired by Candy Box, but is quite different from it.

A Dark Room -
```

If I print only i I get this:

```
<div class=" post" id="post_message_64012736">

            INFO:pyindiegaf<br/>
<br/>
Just testing something, please ignore this :D<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<div style="margin:20px; margin-top:5px; ">
<div class="smallfont" style="margin-bottom:2px">

            Quote:

    </div>
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<td class="quotearea">
<div style="font-style:italic">New browser based game that was directly inspired by Candy Box, but is quite different from it.<br/>
<br/>
A Dark Room -</div>
</td>
</table></div></div>
```

It looks like after finding X  tags it just thinks that it's the end of the main div. As far as Im seeing, every open  has a close tag so it's not like the html is malformed.

So...any guesses as what could be happening here? Im feeling stupid, like Im missing something there?

Thanks!

EDIT: Im not really using that only piece of html, some clarification because with the pure html like that it seems to work.

Im using this URL: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=572913&page=12

Is a vBulleting forum, so all the posts have a class " post".
Im looking for them with bs4 and if they got a keyword in them I will start processing them like this:

```
url = "http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=572913&page=12"
r = requests.get(url)
print "Using url:", url
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
for i in soup.findAll("div",class_=" post"):
    if "INFO:pyindiegaf" in i.text:
        print i
```

Using this method, I get the mentioned result, bs4 stops before ending the whole div block.

Sorry for the confusion, tried to simplify it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem at all. What does `print BeautifulSoup(html).find('div', class_='post').get_text()` print out?

Comment: well, it is working with that piece of html :( . Im not really just using that piece of html, but using requests to get this web: http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=572913&page=12 and checking all the posts. If the posts have "INFO:pyindiegaf" in them, then I start extracting from there.

Comment: I tested it with the HTML you have in your question and it worked, even with the default BS4 HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the site has some malformed HTML which is interfering with the actual parsing. Install `html5lib` (`pip install html5lib`) and use that as your HTML parser instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.neogaf.com/forum/showthread.php?t=572913&page=12'
html = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

for post in soup.find_all('div', class_='post'):
    text = post.get_text()

    if 'INFO:pyindiegaf' in text:
        print(text)
```

It's the most lenient HTML parser you can get. Also, `class_='post'` and `class_=' post'` produce different results.

Since you're scraping a forum, you may want to use [Scrapy](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/) instead. It looks complicated, but the spider will be simpler and much faster than your BeautifulSoup crawler (if you're actually crawling the forum).

Comment: Im trying with this but I don't get anything back, looks like the search is returning zero results? But the html and the class is there...strange.

Comment: @Itxaka: Can you write `html` to a file and host it somewhere? This is pretty odd

Comment: di it with a simple with open("example.html","w") as f: write(html) -> result: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2067658/example.zip and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2067658/example.html if you want to see it online